# Не создается файл и не записываются данные в него (Java)

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток, извините за столь глупый вопрос, являюсь новичком в джаве, однако что не так у меня в коде и как можно было бы его улучшить?

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать запись в созданный файл в указанную мною директорию? Заранее спасибо

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Identifikator {
public static void checkFileExists(final String filepath) {

    //filepath = "C:\\Program Files\\YouLiker\\Identifikator.txt"
    String secretKey = generateRandomKey();
    File dir = new File("C:\\Program Files\\YouLiker");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File("C:\\Program Files\\YouLiker\\Identifikator.txt");

    try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, false);

            if (file.exists() == true) {
                System.out.println(filepath);
            } 

            else if (file.exists() == false) {
                file.createNewFile();
                fileWriter.write(secretKey);
            }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Удалите скрин пожалуйста и вставьте отформатированный код вместо него, тут так не принято делать.

Comment: Посмотрите, что вам стектрейс печатает. Скорее всего, нет прав на запись в Program Files (и это нормально).

Comment: 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\YouLiker\Identifikator.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь) @andreycha

Comment: Да, действительно, в Program Files не записывается. Изменил каталог на C:\YouLiker, все заработало, спасибо). Только ещё вопрос. У меня там есть ещё метод, генерирующий secretKey, он должен записываться в созданный файл, если этого файла не существует. Так вот, у меня просто создается пустой файл, как исправить?

Comment: Оформил ответом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите, что вам стектрейс печатает. Скорее всего, нет прав на запись в Program Files (и это нормально). Используйте другую директорию, например, %APPDATA%, для записи в файл.

Для записи `secretKey` в файл вызовите для `fileWriter` методы `flush()` и `close()`. Пример правильной записи в файл можно посмотреть [тут](http://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.8.php), например.